# Does a Parametric test exist that satisfies the below conditions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric

These past few weeks I've been studying statistics more intensely than ever before but I do have some more advanced background in other fields of mathematics such as *linear algebra*, *numerical analysis*, *differential equations*, *linear regression* (and similar interpolation techniques such as using an orthogonal basis function set) etc. As a result of this prior knowledge and the fact I know that a fundamental part of parametric tests is a distribution with which to fit the data I felt the need to ask whether specifying a particular basis set of functions such that the distribution is limited to some linear combination of said basis functions instead of the more specialised standard distribution functions (**normal distributions**, **hypergeometric distribution**, etc.) would be a viable parametric hypothesis test. I thought that such a parametric test would be so generalised that it would be possible for any distribution to be accurately represented with the right basis set.

Hence it could be called a "semi-parametric test" due to the fact that it has the generalisability of a non-parametric test but the robustness and technique of a parametric test.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a [Box-Cox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform) transformation. I think the real challenge is that the distributions in real data are often much more eratic than the pre-defined family of distributions that this type of method use.

One common problem are spikes. For example, imagine you have a survey containing the number of hours a week that the respondent works and the occupational status. For the first variable you would expect in most Western countries a huge spike at 40 hours a week. For the second variable you would expect to see spikes for common occupations like teachers, but for older cohorts you might expect a spike at farmers. If you think about it it is pretty self-evident, but the problem is that computers don't think

Comment: I don't see anything in the Box-Cox transformation that would allow it to utilise any given basis set of functions.